# How can I filter requests by the contents of the request body?

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the Chrome dev tools to filter through XHRs while visiting a website. I can filter by the request url, but I can't figure out how to filter based on the contents of the request body. Is this possible?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do this in Chrome, but it was easy with Fiddler by modifying the FiddlerScript to hide sessions based on oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString()